Pytorch colors becoming extremely distorted no matter the changes I make
For some reason, when I try to train a model on images, after a while, the images start looking like this:
1st example,
2nd example
I have no idea what could be causing this issue. Any help is appreciated.
I've tried to change the dimensions of the tensors, but I always get errors. I expect the images to not look so distorted.
This has nothing to do with the learning rate or the training data.

GANs are extremely unstable. This is a typical form of mode collapse. You can try training the discriminator more, but overall you're better off moving to a self-supervised loss or SSL + adversarial loss (see VQGAN for examples)
